# Al pasar una Fecha Moment a mi API REST se resta siempre un día

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, angular-material, momentjs

En mi app de Angular uso un datepicker de material angular para obtener unas fechas y estas me llegan de esta manera

[image: moment angular]

Luego esa fecha.toDate()

```
aval.fecha
Fri Feb 17 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (hora estándar de Europa central)
```

la envio a mi API REST para actualizar el valor en una base de datos de SQL en Azure

```
aval.fecha = fecha.toDate();

this.dataServiceAvales.putAval(aval.id, aval)
  .subscribe(
    data => {
```

y en la acción PUT la recibo asi

[image: Put]

Es decir, la fecha que llega a mi API tiene un dia menos de la seleccionada en Angular.

Si en vez de enviar a mi API fecha.toDate() envio fecha.toISOString() directamente obtemgo este valor

```
fecha.toISOString()
'2017-02-16T23:00:00.000Z'
```

Que es también un dia menos y esto entiendo que es un formato UTC valido que no se por que me resta este dia

Entiendo que se debe a un tema de formatos UTC o del locale usado o algo así pero no se como solucionarlo la verdad

Alguna idea, por favor?

Un saludo

Comment: ¿Tienes en cuenta las zonas horarias? ¿Cómo guardas la fecha en la API?

Answer (score 0):

Lo he solucionado haciendo que el datepicker use fechas con el local:es-ES y en formato UTC

En el MaterialModule

```
providers: [
{
  provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS,
  useValue: MY_FORMATS
}
, { provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'es-ES' }
, {
  provide: MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS,
  useValue: { useUtc: true }
}
]
})
export class MaterialModule { }
```